# Compojure: access request params from inside basic-auth function?

Tags: clojure, basic-authentication, compojure, ring

I'm using the ring basic-authentication library available for compojure.  The authenticated? function takes a username and a password in order to authenticate, but in my particular case I need to access other parameters passed in by the user request besides a username and a password.

For instance, consider a case where there are multiple servers, and a user has an account on a particular server.  That user would therefore need to authenticate with (log-on to) a particular server.  Therefore I need his username, password, AND server to do the authentication.

Handling a "normal" case which just calls for a username and password might look something like this (using example sql to hit a database):

```
; curl my_id:my_pass@localhost/my_request

(defn authenticated? [id password]
  (first (select user (where {:id id :password password}) (limit 1))))
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
; curl my_id:my_pass@localhost/my_server/my_request

(defn authenticated? [id password ??server??]
  (first (select user (where {:server server :id id :password password}) (limit 1))))
```

I guess my question is, how do I access all request params from inside authenticated?  Or, alternatively, how do I pass the server id into the authenticated? function?

Thanks.

Comment: You could write a simple ring-middleware (probably using ring.middleware.params) to extract the required parameter from the request and store the value in a `^:dynamic` var before calling the wrapper from ring-authentication. Your `authenticated?` method could then use the var.

Comment: Seriously?  There's not an easier or more straightforward way?

Comment: You could also use extract the parameters, modify your `authenticated?` method to take additional parameter as required and then use `partial` to call it. This basically amounts again to writing a small ring middleware function which parses the request and then calls `wrap-ring-basicauthentication` with `(partial authenticated? yourarg1 yourarg2)`.

Comment: I guess I have no idea how to do any of this stuff.  Perhaps I need to find another framework.  I don't want to write middleware, I want to write a web app.

Comment: Don't despair. A ring middleware is just a simple function taking a handler which returns a function which takes a request and finally applies it the handler to it. I'll write a sketch of a solution as an answer attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In accordance with the comments to the question above, the approach would look like this (just a sketch, I haven't tested whether this works due to lack of a running setup with ring):

```
(defn wrap-basic-auth-server [handler authfn]
 (fn [request]
   (-> request
       (wrap-basic-authentication (partial authfn (get-in request [:params :server])))
       handler)))
```

What's happening here is that the code is assuming that your server url param will have been added by `wrap-params` (from ring.middleware.params) to the request map. `wrap-basic-authentication` is called then with the handler (typical ring middleware, i.e. any other wrapper / handler coming afterwards) and a new (partial) function, which is just your authenticate function which has already swallowed the server arg.

And then instead of just calling `wrap-basic-authentication` in your routes, you need to add `wrap-params` and `wrap-basic-auth-server` and you need your new auth function. E.g.

```
(defn authenticated? [server user pass]
   ... your code ...)

(def app 
    (-> app-routes
        ... potential other wrappers elided ...
        (wrap-params)
        (wrap-basic-auth-server authenticated?)))
```

As I said, I've not tested this code, but it should get you started.